# Java: determine visibility of JFrame on screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, screen, visible

I have a custom Java Swing application that displays its content in two separate and independent `JFrames`. How can I determine if one of my frames - or any displayable Java component in gereneral - is actually really visible on screen? I am speaking of "real visibility" in the meaning that I can actually see it.

**Example**: my application has been made visible using `setVisible(true)`, but when I move any other window or application in front of my application, it gets hidden behind that new window and I am no longer able to see it.

I have used: `frame.isVisible()`, `frame.isShowing()` and `frame.isDisplayable()`.

All three evaluate to `true` no matter if my `JFrame` is actually visible on top of the screen, minimized in the task bar or hidden behind any other window.

Comment: This would require an operating system API since non-Java windows could obscure your frame.  Search on `java windows z-order` and you'll see that it's generally not possible even _within_ a single Java GUI app.

Comment: Any extra information, or alternative approaches to the problem you see here, should be integrated into the original question. This is now closed as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Please note the original duplicate target was deleted, and was just minutes ago edited by a moderator to point to another non-deleted target.